# CodeRush - Commenting out whole sections of code

Tags: devexpress, coderush

Is there a way to comment out a chunk of code quickly using CodeRush ?

```
        'For narCounter = 0 To UBound(arPDFFiles)
        '    'Add the PDF File Names to the Data Table.
        '    rowPDF = dtPDF.NewRow
        '    rowPDF("PDFDocument") = arPDFFiles(narCounter)
        '    dtPDF.Rows.Add(rowPDF)
        'Next
```

Comment: Why not add your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the CodeRush Pro has the Selection Comment feature. This feature adds the capability to quickly comment or uncomment a multi-line block of code (or any text in the code editor) via a single shortcut. In Visual Basic, it is (‘)(Apostrophe) and in CSharp (or C++), it is (/) (Slash). Note that if you are using CodeRush Xpress, it doesn't have this feature. [Here](http://www.skorkin.com/2010/11/selection-quick-commentuncomment/) is some more info on this.

Comment: Additionally it should be noted that if you are based using a uk keyboard the VB.Net binding is by default set to # rather than '

Comment: This is due to the way keybindings are stored. the US code for ' and the Uk code for # are apparently the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done using CodeRush.  Select a code and press the ' button.

Comment: See my comment on Alex's Answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ctr+E, C which is already built into Visual Studio

Comment: The CodeRush shortcut (') is easier, and a lot more intuitive.

Comment: @cometbill: To a vb developer it might be more intuitive, but for a c# developer maybe not. To be honest I didn't know about that shortcut myself, and I use CodeRush quite a bit.

Comment: The C# shortcut to the same feature is / (slash). This is the same key as used in making single line comments in c# itself. This allows the Learning curve to be very low in this area.

Comment: I suspect @cometbill references the '(apostrophe) because he is a vb dev. His original question related to VB.net, but we've obviously considered c# devs in our implementation.

Comment: Hey Ole_Brun could you contact me via email (roryb@devexpress.com) and I'll see if I can't find out what's wrong here. It's almost  sounds like a VB user has been messing with your settings. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl K + C in VS does this too.